# Issue with railscast# 238 , date_select not working with rails 4.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

I am trying railscast#238.
I am using rails 4 and mongoid(4.0.0).When trying to add published_on field with date_select helper. It is not able to save into collection.
Then, I added :published_on in the permit function. But then also I am getting error.
I also tried including Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes but it is not found. I think its been removed from mongoid.
Below is the error in the log file:

## Log File

> Processing by ArticlesController#update as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3+y5UUckEDqJRPwdibdlhwAxKHi1g2ECF/4SzFNVbJE=", "article"=>{"name"=>"sachin", "published_on(1i)"=>"2013", "published_on(2i)"=>"4", "published_on(3i)"=>"10", "content"=>"s'up?"}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"}
>     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongs_development collection=articles selector={"_id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5178ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
>
> Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute (
>   Problem:
>     Attempted to set a value for 'published_on(1i)' which is not allowed on the model Article.
>   Summary:
>     Without including Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic in your model and the attribute does not already exist in the attributes hash, attempting to call Article#published_on(1i)= for it is not allowed. This is also triggered by passing the attribute to any method that accepts an attributes hash, and is raised instead of getting a NoMethodError.
>   Resolution:
>     You can include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic if you expect to be writing values for undefined fields often.):
>     app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
>     app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:43:in`update'

If i remove published_on from permit:

> arameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3+y5UUckEDqJRPwdibdlhwAxKHi1g2ECF/4SzFNVbJE=", "article"=>{"name"=>"sachin", "published_on(1i)"=>"2013", "published_on(2i)"=>"9", "published_on(3i)"=>"10", "content"=>"s'up?"}, "commit"=>"Update Article", "id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"}
>     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.6187ms)
>     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongs_development collection=articles selector={"_id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.2012ms)
>   Unpermitted parameters: published_on(1i), published_on(2i), published_on(3i)
>   Redirected to

```
       http://localhost:3000/articles/522f4ce6f0b1817131000001
```

Completed 302 Found in 5ms

> Started GET "/articles/522f4ce6f0b1817131000001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-10 23:19:34 +0530
>   Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"}
>     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongs_development collection=articles selector={"_id"=>"522f4ce6f0b1817131000001"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3569ms)
>     Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.4ms)

Can someone give solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes` in your document class.

In Mongoid 4.0 you also need to define that module in yor `lib/` folder.
See detailed explanation in [this blog](http://roodyruby.tumblr.com/post/67651747866/multi-parameter-attributes-support-for-mongoid-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you have the function

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit!(:published_on)
end

**But you also need...**

```
Article.create(article_params)
```

**NOT**

```
Article.create(params[:article])
```

Hope this helps,

-Brian